# Issue in compiling libjpeg-turbo of glmark2 for android

Tags: android, assembly, arm, gpu, neon

I tried cross compiling glmark2 for android, it got assembler error:

```
external/glmark2-master/android/jni/src/libjpeg-turbo/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S: Assembler messages:
external/glmark2-master/android/jni/src/libjpeg-turbo/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:30: Error: unknown pseudo-op: .fpu'external/glmark2-master/android/jni/src/libjpeg-turbo/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:31: Error: unknown architecturearmv7a'

external/glmark2-master/android/jni/src/libjpeg-turbo/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:32: Error: unknown pseudo-op: .object_arch' external/glmark2-master/android/jni/src/libjpeg-turbo/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:33: Error: unknown pseudo-op:.arm'
external/glmark2-master/android/jni/src/libjpeg-turbo/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:184: Warning: unknown register 'r0' -- .req ignored
external/glmark2-master/android/jni/src/libjpeg-turbo/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:185: Warning: unknown register 'r1' -- .req ignored
external/glmark2-master/android/jni/src/libjpeg-turbo/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:186: Warning: unknown register 'r2' -- .req ignored
external/glmark2-master/android/jni/src/libjpeg-turbo/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:187: Warning: unknown register 'r3' -- .req ignored
...
...
```

I doubt this may be due to the compiler not configured for neon coprocessor instruction, 
So I added the following instruction in `Android.mk`.

```
LOCAL_ARM_NEON := true
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jsimd_arm_neon.S.neon
```

But the issue is not resolved after the above change. I googled a lot about similar issue, i don't find any solution for same.

Thanks

Comment: It looks more like you're using the wrong assembler entirely.

Comment: I am compiling this project with Android source code. Above compilation errors may be due to "--with-fpu=vfp" is not configured for ARM64 gcc toolchain but  it is configured for ARM32. I don't know the exact root cause of this issue.

Comment: Well, if you're feeding 32-bit assembly code into an AArch64 assembler, my first comment definitely stands. The two instruction sets are not directly compatible.

Comment: thanks.. got it. May be need to port it for AARCH64.